# A clearcase equivalent of svn blame / git blame?

Tags: version-control, clearcase, equivalent, blame

In Rational Software's Clearcase, is there a `cleartool` subcommand, or other command line tool, equivalent to the `blame` command in SVN or in git?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The closest one would be with [`cleartool annotate`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_annotate.htm):

> The annotate command lists the contents of a version, annotating each line to indicate when, and in which version, the line was added.
> You can customize the annotations using the `–fmt` option, which is described in the [`fmt_ccase` reference page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm).
> By default, annotate writes its output to a file whose file-name extension is `.ann`.

To have the output on the terminal, like SVN or git blame, a command-line might be:

```
cleartool annotate -out - source_file_path
```

Comment: Thank you @Nikola for updating those old links!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send command output to stdout.

`cleartool annotate -out - foo.c`

Comment: I upvoted you, but this is really an improvement to the accepted answer, so I edited it in there.