# ClearCase SCM Adapter support for annotate

Tags: clearcase, annotate

I wanted to annotate some code with version history. This is easy in Eclipse when using SVN, but the Rational ClearCase SCM Adapter plugin doesn't appear to support it.

I quick Google search reveals that on the command line ClearCase supports annotate via:
        cleartool annotate -out - -fmt "%Vn |" -rm -nheader util.c

I also found a number of non-free plugins that support annotate.
Any free alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`cleartool annotate`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6826119/6309) is the only form of annotation (or "blame") for ClearCase, and isn't available through the official plugins (ClearCase SCM adapter, or the CCRC plugin)

That is why you will fond some non-free option like:

- [annotate add-on](http://www.pluginsmithy.com/m/en/products/annotate-plugin.html)
- [Visual Annotate](http://www.gomidjets.com/annotate.php) (could have a free edition soon, according to his author [Tamir Gefen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/138479/tamir-gefen))
- [FishEye & Crucible](http://www.pixsoftware.nl/nl/news/62-developer-tools/354-fisheye-and-crucible-22-released-now-with-git-and-clearcase), although [that stopped 4th April 2012, with FishEye 2.8](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/FISHEYE/End+of+Support+Announcement+for+IBM+ClearCase).

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio you can set it up to run the cleartool command line option (Using the Tools->External Tools...).
It seems like eclipse has a similar feature ("[FAQ How do I add my own external tools?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_add_my_own_external_tools?)")

```
Command: \installationpath\cleartool.exe
Arguments: annotate -nheader $(ItemPath)
Initial directory: $(ItemDir)
```

After it creates the file you can open in your favorite editor.

I only mention it because it might be an option as it is free.
It is easier then using the command line excluding when my project files have the wrong capitalization which causes cleartool to not work and I find myself either update the `.vcproj` or using the command line.