# Annotate ("blame") in CCRC?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

In base ClearCase there is a "SVN blame"-style command called "Annotate" that shows who wrote each line in a versioned element.

Is there a way to annotate using the remote client (CCRC)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only though command-line, for full ClearCase:

See: [`cleartool annotate`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_annotate.htm) (or you have [other commercial alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169735/clearcase-scm-adapter-support-for-annotate), including [Tamir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/138479/tamir-gefen)'s one [Visual Annotate](http://www.gomidjets.com/annotate.php), which has a beta supporting CCRC)

But `cleartool` isn't available for CCRC.
CCRC has a CLI (command line interface) though.

[This thread](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=250992) mentions:

> The **`annotate`** command should be supported in both the CCRC Gui and command line (at least the command line to be equivalent to full ClearCase.
>   Full CC has never had a gui for annotate but that is another problem).

Comment: @Markus, we work these days to extend "Visual Annotate" to support CCRC and remote clients. If you'd like to try it when it's ready, please send an email to beta at gomidjets dot com

Comment: The CCRC CLI does not seem to have the annotate command. I guess we will have to go with cleartool or the Visual Annotate tool. Thanks for your help!