# Cleartool annotate command giving error - Not an object in a vob:"java file"

Tags: clearcase, cleartool, annotate, vob

I am new to clearcase and I am trying to generate a blame file using annotate command, but I am getting the following error :

> cleartool: Error: Not an object in a vob: "App.java"

I followed these steps :

1. Created a view in clearcase explorer
2. Browsed  to the location (C:\test_view)
3. Ran: cleartool annotate App.java

This resulted in the following -

> cleartool: Error: Not an object in a vob: "App.java".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please create VOBs through create VOB program.

Then create dynamic view using clearcase explorer.

Mount the VOBs on the dynamic view.

Once mounted, in the view explorer, right click and add text file.

rt-click text file to add to source and then checkin the file after making the necessary changes.

from command prompt go to the VOB and run 
cleartool annotate

Z:>cd test_tut_element_vob

Z:\test_tut_element_vob>cleartool annotate TestFile.txt
Annotated result written to "TestFile.txt.ann".[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot execute cleartool commands on elements (versioned files or folder) directly in a snapshot root folder like `c:\test_View`.

You need to edit its config spec:

```
cd c:\test_View
cleartool edcs
```

Add [selection rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6578525/6309) (like at least `element * /main/LATEST`, unless this is an UCM view, in which case selection rules are already there), and **load rules** in order to load at least the content of a Vob.

Then you can go within the vob and do some `cleartool annotate`.

```
cd c:\test_view\avob
cleartool annotate afile
```

Note: if your file App.java is not yet versioned, [you would need to add it to source control (in any folder in `c:\test_view\avob`), with `cleartool mkelem`, or, for multiple files, `clearfsimport`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24730460/6309).

Comment: when running command cleartool.edcs on c:\test_view getting error: Error: Cannot get view info for current view: not a ClearCase object.

Comment: my test_view is a web view i have checked it in show properties option of view

Comment: @akshayjain web view? Are you running ClearCase 8.x and/or CCRC? In that case, replace cleartool with rcleartool (http://stackoverflow.com/a/21577362/6309). Or use the ClearTeam explorer to access the config spec that way.

Comment: i tried the command cleartool annotate<vob tag> filename and now the error is could not find the path of the file.                                                this vob is public and is on some other machine.                                         @Vonc i am using clearcase 8.0.0 version

Comment: @akshayjain see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/13286838/6309. What version of ClearCase are you using? What is the exact  full complete command that you have typed?

Comment: i am using clearcase veriosn 8.0.0 and the command i have typed               1.cleartool annotate App.java and 2.cleartool annotate</clinical> App.java

Comment: @akshayjain `cleartool annotate/clinical` would not work: you don't add a vob tag to a command. `cleartool annotate App.java` would work if `App.java` has been added to source control in a Vob (like `/clinical`). What is your current path when you  type that command? What `cleartool ls` returns?

Comment: cleartool ls returining cleartool: Error: Pathname is not within a VOB: "."

Comment: I read your ans cleartool ls :Error but when i trying                            cleartool setview test_view is giving error                                                               cleartool: Error: Unrecognized command: "setview"

Comment: @akshayjain setview is for dynamic view only, which are not supported in Cleartool 8.0.0. And a view on `C:\` is not a dynamic view anyway. It is a snapshot view or a web view (CCRC).

Comment: @akshayjain cleartool ls only works in a vob within a view: `c:\test_view\avob\...`.

Comment: i have created a dynamic view and  i have created vobs which are showing under that view now how to add the code in the vobs and then annotate them. here the path is where i am Y:\test_akshay> here y is my view and test_akshay is my vob now how to add file and folders in this vob

Comment: @akshayjain Great! But don't bother with setview. Use the full path of the dynamic view: `M:\myView\avob\...`

Comment: is there a way to apply annotate and lshistory command on web view??

Comment: @akshayjain yes, with rcleartool I mentioned above in the comments, and in http://stackoverflow.com/a/21577362/6309.