# CRCLI2002E Unrecognized command: "annotate"

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

Searched it and some said annotate is not available in rcleartool.

I have a web view so i have to use rcleartool instead of cleartool.

What are the alternatives to get the **annotate** result on a web view.

Answer (score 1):

[cleartool annotate](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_annotate.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-0) is indeed documented as a cleartool command only.

There is no native alternative in CCRC and web views, but I suggests a commercial alternative in "[Annotate (“blame”) in CCRC?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13286838/6309)".

Comment: can i create a dynamic view instead of web view for the remote VOB

Comment: @akshayjain it depends on your version of CCRC: if 8.0.1+, dynamic views are supported.

Comment: 8.0.0.v20130308_1624 is the version of my rcleartool

Comment: @akshayjain yes, ClearTeam 8.x supports dynamic views (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23105722/clearcase-get-file-from-repository/23106205#23106205). But I don't think it supports annotate on said dynamic views. (unless the `cleartool` command is available, instead of only `rcleartool`)

Comment: How to create a dynamic view with remote vob because when i am creating the dyamic view with configuration same as web view but it is not creating the view with that vob only local vob are showing in that view

Comment: and in other machine i have no option to create a dynamic view in clear case explorer only web view is available

Comment: @akshayjain do you have the native client installed, as mentioned in https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/t_use_dyn_views.htm? See also https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/t_ccteam_base_mkview.htm, about CleaCase node.

Answer (score 1):

ClearCase has two different client environments, the ClearCase Local Client (CCLC - sometimes referred to as the "thick client") and the ClearCase Remote Client (CCRC).  CCLC supports dynamic views and snapshot views and includes the 'cleartool' command.  CCRC supports automatic views and Web views and includes the 'rcleartool' ("remote cleartool") command.  [About ClearCase views](http://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/c_ccview.htm) provides more details.  You can install one or the other or both on the same machine.

As the name implies, CCLC must be on the same Local Area Network (LAN) as the ClearCase VOB servers.  If you are not on the same LAN as the VOB servers, using a remote access solution (ssh, telnet, X, Remote Desktop, etc.) to another machine with CCLC on the same LAN as the VOB servers is an option.