# How to find which CRs in clearcase modified given lines in source code file (like 'git blame -L' does)?

Tags: git, clearcase, cleartool, clearquest

I have tried to find a way in **clearcase**, using `cleartool` to identify CRs - which introduced specific lines in source code for a given file. I'm looking for equivalent or very similar functionality to:

`git blame -L <line_num1>,<line_num2> <filename>`

, which is documented at [`git blame`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame) .

Is it possible to query **clearcase** repository to retrieve this information ?

I can `grep` trough all visible file branches, but this is not exactly what I'm searching for.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does CR mean a Change Request? Do you use UCM?

Comment: CR means Change Request, which is effectively branch in clearcase and generated by clearquest. I think UCM is not used in my case. @Tamir-Gefen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main command, with classic ClearCase, is [`cleartool annotate`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_annotate.htm) (you also have [some alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13169891/6309)).

This isn't exactly like `git blame -L`, as you cannot limit to a portion of a file.

With the long format, that would give:

```
cleartool annotate -long msg.c

Annotated result written to "msg.c.ann".
type  msg.c.ann
02-Apr-99.10:51:54 ##### Steve (scd.user@reach)\main\rel2_bugfix\1
a test
.
.
.
-------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------
##### 01-Apr-99.16:19:25 scd \main\1              | #include "hello.h"
##### 02-Apr-99.10:51:54 scd \main\rel2_bugfix\1  | /* a test */
##### 01-Apr-99.16:19:25 scd \main\1              |
.
.
.
##### .                                           |char *
##### .                                           | hello_msg() {
```

That applies to *one* file (or list of files separated by a space)

Comment: I missed the fact that `cleartool annotate -long` prints branches as well, I suppose this is the best - **clearcase** can provide. Thanks @VonC